# Very New. Grid issue in CSS

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

Hey I have this problem when trying to make simple grids. I have an unordered list with four list elements in it. Using grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows I set four columns and one row but in the browser its showing two columns and two rows which makes no sense to me.

If I assign all the list items
the row  1/2
as shown in comment below in the CSS the problem is fixed
but this seems like an unnecessary  line of code from what I know. If someone would help explain the mechanics of what is happening so I will stop running into this problem it would be great. Either what I am missing or why I need to specify the row. It's just nagging in the back of my head.

```css
* {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

head {
  display: none;
}

body {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

ul {
  background: white;
  width: max-content;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, max-content);
  grid-template-rows: max-content;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 3px;
  /* grid-row: 1/2; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Image Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Snapshots</h1>
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li><a href="images/fireworks.jpg" title="A fireworks display"><img src="images/fireworksTHBN.jpg" alt="Fireworks>"</a></li>
    <li><a href="images/coffee.jpg" title="A fireworks display"><img src="images/coffeeTHBN.jpg" alt="Fireworks>"</a></li>
    <li><a href="images/rose.jpg" title="A fireworks display"><img src="images/roseTHBN.jpg" alt="Fireworks>"</a></li>
    <li><a href="images/bigben.jpg" title="A fireworks display"><img src="images/bigbenTHBN.jpg" alt="Fireworks>"</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Probably related to the size of the images. If you can demonstrate this WITH proper linked images we might be able to help.

Comment: -You Should Properly formate your html as you didn't close img tag properly

Answer (score 0):

You have one very simple problem in your syntax

```html
<li>
  <a href="images/fireworks.jpg" title="A fireworks display">
    <img src="images/fireworksTHBN.jpg" alt="Fireworks>"
  </a>
 </li>
```

Your `<img>` tag is not properly closed

I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for and then it will work as expected, otherwise it just takes the `<a>` as another element which explains the 4 items in the grid.

```html
<li>
  <a href="images/fireworks.jpg" title="A fireworks display">
    <img src="images/fireworksTHBN.jpg" alt="Fireworks">
  </a>
 </li>
```